# ethernet goes down after some time after boot

Tags: debian, network-interface, ethernet

Am on debian 10 and the ethernet connection goes down after some time after boot.

**Workaround:** `sudo systemctl restart networking`

**Note:** Second computer with different motherboard network card that does this problem. Second computer was working till today :(.

**Ethernet card:**

`04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)`

**Kernel logs when happens:**

`Apr  4 12:46:13  kernel: [  214.065598] SGI XFS with ACLs, security attributes, realtime, no debug enabled Apr  4 12:46:13  kernel: [  214.078066] JFS: nTxBlock = 8192, nTxLock = 65536 Apr  4 12:46:13  kernel: [  214.108306] QNX4 filesystem 0.2.3 registered.`

**/etc/network/interfaces:**

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp4s0
auto enp4s0
iface enp4s0 inet manual

allow-hotplug br0
auto br0
iface br0 inet dhcp
        pre-up { brctl addbr br0 && brctl addif br0 enp4s0; } || true
        bridge_port enp4s0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
```

Comment: I would try comenting out "auto br0" and "auto enp4s0" since it's possible "auto" may be over riding "allow-hotplug". I have a bridge and I don't use "auto" just "allow-hotplug".

Comment: @CinaedSimson removing `auto` would not bring up the interface at boot....

Comment: Do you have the right firmware for your boards installed?